# How to grant write access to only a person within Rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am little bit confused about setting permissions in Rules section of my Firebase database.

I am working on an app (which is a Book actually) and the app must be updated by only one person with this email address: `someone@gmail.com`. Therefore the rest of people, either authenticated or not, must not be able to modify the contents, but they are allowed to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Firebase Security Rules API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/), you'll see that the user's email address (if there is one) is made available via [`auth.token.email`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken).

So to grant write access to the entire database to the user with the `someone@gmail.com` email address and read access to *everyone* else, you could define rules like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.token.email === 'someone@gmail.com'"
    }
}
```

Said rules would grant read access to *everyone*. If you wanted to grant read access only to authenticated users, you could use:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth !== null",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.token.email === 'someone@gmail.com'"
    }
}
```